Deploying .NET project on Raspbian
I am trying to test a .NET POC where I have just for test case a console application with two custom libraries and I need to deploy it on a raspberryPI 3 B+ with Raspbian on it.
I Installed dotnet on the raspbian. Installation went ok. After adding path to dotnet, dotnet command workds well.
I  released the .NET project as self contained release based on linux-arm architectre. The problem i have is that in release directory, there are all class libraries but im missing the console application project that is also supposed to be a .dll??? Hence I have no entry point to run the dotnet command like

dotnet Project.POC.Console.dll

Is there anything else needed for the .NET project to be run on raspbian?

The mistake i did was that i copied the content of release directory. I was supposed to publish the project into target directory for given architecture, which after all creates the entry point dll with all refferenced projects.

You also need to download and install .NET on raspbian to run the application.
